# Determine if Timeout object was created by setTimeout or setInterval

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a property of an object that stores the ID of a timeout object. This ID could either be the ID returned by `setTimeout` or by `setInterval`.

```
function populateWithTimeoutOrInterval(obj) {
    if (/* Condition */) {
        obj.timeoutID = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    } else {
        obj.timeoutID = setInterval(callback, ms);
    }
}
```

Now say I need to create a function like this.

```
function foo(obj) {
    return isInterval(obj) ? doStuffAsInterval(obj) : doStuffAsTimeout(obj);
}
```

What would the body of `isInterval` need to be?

In addition, how would I clear such an object?

The obvious answer would be to add an additional property to `obj` if possible containing whether `timeoutID` is a timeout or interval, but is there a way to do all of the above without that extra property?

Answer (score 1):

You can do two properties in and object which can save the setTimeout and setInterval Id like this:

```
// if you don't send timeout it will be setInterval
function populateWithTimeoutOrInterval(obj, timeOut = false) {
    if (timeOut) {
        obj.timeoutID = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    } else {
        obj.intervalID = setInterval(callback, ms);
    }
}

const isInterval = obj => obj.intervalID === -1 ? true: false;
```

When you complete the execution with setInterval or timeout, you must be clearing it after that change the `ID` status like this:

```
doStuffAsInterval(obj) {
    // do your stuff

    // after clearing the interval
    obj.intervalID = -1;
}


doStuffAsTimeout(obj) {
    // do your stuff

    // after clearing the interval
    obj.timeoutID = -1;
}
```